# java.lang.exceptionininitializererror in android ndk

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm trying simple addition program in android ndk. But I'm getting the following exception -

```
java.lang.exceptionininitializererror
```

Java File-

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private native void MyMethod(int a,int b);  
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MyMethod(4,5);
    }

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("native"); // here i'm getting exception
    }

}
```

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
LOCAL_MODULE    := native
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := native.c
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

native.c

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <android/log.h>

#define DEBUG_TAG "NDKSetupActivity"

void Java_com_example_additionndk_MainActivity_MyMethod(JNIEnv * env, jobject this, jint a,jint b)
{
    jint c=a+b;
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, DEBUG_TAG, "addition: %d", c);
}
```

Comment: Can you show the whole stack trace?

Comment: ...and any relevant-looking log messages from shortly before the exception, e.g. complaints from the VM or dlopen()?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error once when running the sample ndk (hello-jni). It's because the android sdk version is not compatible (default of the example is 1.5). Try to switch the compatible sdk and modifiy manifest . 
Another case is you haven't build the .c to .so. Use ndk-build from cygwin64.